# specific records using procedure in mysql without using the static values in the table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
 Create table company(id int, name varchar(20), designation varchar(20), parent int);
  Insert into company values(1,'shyam', 'VP', NULL);
  Insert into company values(2,’sundar’, 'GM', 1);
  Insert into company values(3,'rajan', 'M', 2);
  Insert into company values(4,'karthik', 'Lead', 3);
  Insert into company values(5,'raj', 'Developer',4);
  Insert into company values(6,'sami', 'Developer', 4);
  Insert into company values(7,'diva', 'Lead', 3);
  Insert into company values(8,'dina', 'Developer', 7);
  Insert into company values(9,'mahe','Developer', 7); `
```

The table is created. There are two teams in the table. Both
 are under GM and M, each team contains a lead and two developers.

Now, I need to create a `procedure` with a parameter. When I give input on
 calling the ID, I need the entire team with GM, M, lead and two
 developers.

**For example:**

If I am giving the input as 8, I need to
 select sundar, rajan, diva, dina, mahe from the table.

If I am giving input as 6, I enter code here need to select sundar, rajan, karthik, raj and sami.

Please help without using the values in the table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the hierarchy always 4 levels deep? What should the procedure return if the input is a Lead or M? Should the VP always be excluded?